# Building a DIY projector. LED driver voltage output 24-36V, 100 watt LED voltage 32-38V. The LED driver is short 2 volts, would this matter much?

Tags: voltage, current, diy

I'm in the process of putting all these pieces together to build a DIY projector.

- [Lens](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32651924613.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4da84c4d9fZUvT)
- [LCD+Board](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32366781090.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4doExZxZ)
- [Fresnel](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32704063176.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dmfbScW)
- [Condenser lens](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32738484551.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dmfbScW)
- [LED](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32251460216.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dmfbScW)

The only part I'm missing in this build is a compatible power supply unit for North America.

I found [this led power supply,](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32837925422.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.4cd83c00ykDWlA&mp=1) but it is short 2 volts on the maximum voltage rating.

Would this work well with this setup? I need to power the LED and the wattage is suitable as well the voltage for the most part but the maximum is short 2 volts at only 36 volts when the maximum on the led is 38.

Does this matter much?

I'd like to power the fans from this as well.

Comment: I wouldn't run the fan from the constant current LED driver.

Answer (score 1):

Buying parts from AliExpress can give you some great bargains but the downside is that the "datasheets" are often very limited in information content and accuracy. That said, for the LED the 32-38V range probably encompasses all 3 of:

- part-to-part variation
- higher forward voltage at higher operating temperature
- gradual increase in forward voltage over lifetime

The actual forward voltage also is an (increasing) function of the forward current, though typically the specified forward voltage will be at a particular fixed current.

If you are not so unlucky as to get the very worst parts from the manufacturer's binning, and if you do a good job of keeping it cool (which is not at all trivial with these high power LEDs), and perhaps if you're willing to accept a small reduction in light output, it will likely work fine.

You say you'd like to power the fans from this supply also. That might be possible but it would really restrict your options in terms of fan selection. It would also mean that you couldn't keep the fan running after shutting down the LEDs, which could mean problems with heat soakback. I'd probably just use fans that run directly on mains voltage.

Comment: Usualy the optimal specified current and therefore the light output is achieved near the upper value in the voltage range. In this case closer to 38V than 32V. At 36V the projector could be weaker than expected. But as pericynthion said, at lower temperatures it can be OK. It can also be OK if you don't need the maximum power. You must put a very large, massive, heatsink, with long fans. You can build it yourself with alu profiles. I would even consider water cooling. It will make the LED last longer and be more efficient.

Comment: Powering the fan separately is a good idea as it could run after the light turns off and still hot. But I would use a second power supply, 12V or so. The LED power supply being turned on and off from the main power line, with a rocker switch for example. While the fan could be monitored with a temperature sensor or a thermal protector switch.

Comment: For what white LEDs, the forward voltage decreases with increasing temperature.  See:  https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLampThermalManagement.pdf